# SQL Group By Function

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to filter data about state that contains more than one location. My code is:

```
SELECT
  cc.country_id,
  cc.country_name,
  l.city,
  l.street_address,
  l.postal_code,
  l.state_province,
  count(*)
  FROM locations l, countries cc
 WHERE l.country_id = cc.country_id
 ORDER BY cc.country_id
 GROUP BY (cc.country_id, cc.country_name)
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

And i get a following message:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 6 Column: 9
```

What is the problem?

Comment: ***state** that contains more than one location* Did you mean to find **countries** that have more than one location?

Comment: Note that the `ORDER BY` clause is not in the correct place within the query. According to the [select syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#i2065706), it must be placed after the `HAVING` clause.

Answer (score 2):

All the fields which are not in an aggregation function (count, sum, avg, etc.) must be in the group by clause

so there, you should have

```
group by cc.country_id, cc.country_name, 
         l.city, l.street_address, l.postal_code, l.state_province
```

or you should remove these fields from select clause, or put them in an aggregation function in the select clause, or change your query.

by the way, it would be better to use the join syntax

replacing

```
FROM locations l, countries cc
 where l.country_id = cc.country_id
```

by

```
FROM location l
inner join countries cc on l.country_id = cc.country_id
```

and finally, `ORDER BY` must be the last statement in a query

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues with the query:

1. The `group by` needs all the fields
2. The `order by` is in the wrong place
3. It uses implicit rather than explicit `join` syntax

The following should work:

```
 SELECT cc.country_id, cc.country_name, l.city, l.street_address,
        l.postal_code, l.state_province, count (*)
 FROM locations l join
      countries cc
      on l.country_id = cc.country_id
 group by cc.country_id, cc.country_name, l.city, l.street_address,
          l.postal_code, l.state_province
 having count(*) > 1
 order by cc.country_id;
```

However, if you want to count rows within a *country*, then remove the additional fields:

```
 SELECT cc.country_id, cc.country_name, count (*)
 FROM locations l join
      countries cc
      on l.country_id = cc.country_id
 group by cc.country_id, cc.country_name
 having count(*) > 1
 order by cc.country_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage windowing functions

```
SELECT c.country_id, c.country_name, l.city, l.street_address, l.postal_code, l.state_province, l.l_count 
  FROM countries c JOIN 
(
  SELECT country_id, city, street_address, postal_code, state_province,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY country_id) l_count
    FROM locations
) l
    ON l.country_id = c.country_id
 WHERE l.l_count > 1
 ORDER BY c.country_id
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ee5d9/1)** demo